# Why am I unable to retrieve the full list of cookies when using Selenium with Python3?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I am trying to use Python3 & selenium to login to a site and extract the cookies so I can use them for a later call. However, I'm unable to retrieve the complete set of cookies.

For example, when I go to the post-authentication page manually, I can see the full list of cookie tokens from the developer tools browser GUI. These are:
*csn*, *cpn*, _ga, didomi_token, euconsent-v2, _ga_T0L2RVVYNH, _gid, _gat_gtag_UA_114622452_16, .lpac, XSRF-TOKEN, and Extranet_AL.

If I copy this complete block and use it in a subsequent request (something like)

```
cookies = {
    "cookies" : "_csn_: accepted, _cpn_: accepted....... etc.,"
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0",
    }
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=2)
```

This works fine.

However, if I pull the cookies programatically from selenium,
`pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("session.pkl", "wb"))`

then I only get the following tokens:
.lpac, XSRF-TOKEN, Extranet_AL, *csn*, and *cpn*

.. and they are insufficient to authenticate with the above requests.get() command.

I have double checked that selenium is switching to the correct page and I can read the html elements, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a hang up from changing tabs.

Note: I've tried Chrome and Firefox webdrivers... I'm not tied to either but both show the same problem.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: check my solution for cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there is an issue creating a cookie string based on the collected cookies. Check this:

```
cookies_json = self.driver.get_cookies()
cookies_str = ''.join(map(lambda c: '%s=%s; ' % (c['name'], c['value']), cookies_json))    
response = requests.get( url, headers={'cookie': cookies_str, 'User-Agent': userAgent})
```